# Python - how can i read numbers in a file as integers but with headings?

Tags: python, file, integer

I have a file that has a bunch of numbers, but there are headings that are keeping me from doing much. The file looks like this:

```
x: 
1 2 3 4 

f: 
5 6 7 8

h:
9 10 11 12 13
```

so I have this program which i believe will help me access the numbers but I get an error message about it.

```
filename = input('file: ')
f = open(filename, 'r')
output=[]
w, h = map(int,lines.split())
x=[]
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i == h:
        break
    x.append(map(int,line.split()[:w]))
output.append(x)
```

So i tried striping the headers, but I get an error message about it being a string and such.

```
filename = input('file: ')
f = open(filename, 'r')
output=[]
func = f.readline()
lines = func.strip('x').strip('f').strip('h').split()
w, h = map(int,lines.split())
x=[]
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i == h:
         break
    x.append(map(int,line.split()[:w]))
output.append(x)
```

any advice?

Comment: What is the error that you get ?

Comment: it's about the headers and how i cant make 'x', etc. an integer

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output? Is it just a list of numbers or are the headings relevant? I mean do you expect `{'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'f': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'h': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]}` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`

Answer (score 0):

If the heading are distinct, parse as follows?

```
x -> [1,2,3,4]
f -> [5,6,7,8]
h -> [9,10,11,12,13]
```

Is this what you are after?

Comment: yes! i want them in an array. i'm having problems getting them not as strings, but with the headings, i'm running into issues.

Comment: What do yo allow for the headings?  Can you write a regex for it?

Answer (score 0):

Just read file normally and strip all characters? Quick code, haven't tested but you should be able to easily adapt.

```
import re

 with open (filename, "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
       data =re.sub(r"\D", "", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

parsefile.py:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'rU') as data:
    mydict = {}
    for line in data:
        varname = re.search('(\w+):', line)
        if varname:
            mydict[varname.group(1)] = [int(num) for num in data.next().split()]
    print 'x = ', mydict['x']
    print 'f = ', mydict['f']
    print 'h = ', mydict['h']
```

file.txt:

```
x: 
1 2 3 4 

f: 
5 6 7 8

h:
9 10 11 12 13
```

output:

```
(parsedigitsheaders)macbook:parsedigitsheaders joeyoung$ python parsefile.py 
x =  [1, 2, 3, 4]
f =  [5, 6, 7, 8]
h =  [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```